# Parameter sql query not working with special quote like this ’

Tags: python, sql, teradata

Select statement:

```
self.selectSQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM DIM WHERE REPORT_NAME=?'

cur.execute(sqlQuery,trans)
```

I am using a parameterized query and there are some single quotes in the string and there is this character/string which is not working property

```
Cantons De L’est
```

When I print the list of parameter it looks correct for `'`

```
("St. John's",)
("St. John's",)
('Edmonton',)
('Victoria',)
('Cantons De L’est',)
```

Any solution for this other than replace it to `'`

Comment: use `replace` function?

Comment: Yes, I have done this but I wanted to know if there is any sql solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Java(Script) example for pre-formatting: param1.replaceAll("'","''");

Comment: What value is stored in the database? The "Right Single Quotation Mark" U+2019 shown in your parameter list is not available in "Teradata LATIN". If you need to pass that value, you should use a Unicode session character set (e.g. UTF8) when creating the connection instead of the default "ASCII".

Answer (score 0):

Check your collation / charset defined for column / table / db

Comment: it is different, not ' but ’

Comment: Sorry, i did missreading..  in this case i guess you may check collation / charset.. changed my answer